# centos multipath /dev/mapper dont map partitions

Tags: centos, multipath

On SERVER1 I have the following output of dmsetup info -C:

```
Name                                Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID                                                                
3600000e00d290000002930c300100000p3 253  44 L--w    0    1      0 
part3-mpath-3600000e00d290000002930c300100000                       
3600000e00d290000002930c300100000p2 253  31 L--w    0    1      0 
part2-mpath-3600000e00d290000002930c300100000                       
3600000e00d290000002930c300100000p1 253  20 L--w    0    1      0 
part1-mpath-3600000e00d290000002930c300100000                       
3600000e00d290000002930c300100000   253   4 L--w    5    1      0 
mpath-3600000e00d290000002930c300100000                             
3600000e00d290000002930c300100000p5 253  60 L--w    0    1      0 
part5-mpath-3600000e00d290000002930c300100000                       
3600000e00d290000002930c300100000p4 253  55 L--w    0    1      0 
part4-mpath-3600000e00d290000002930c300100000
```

So all the partions are show up, too. On SERVER2 I get the following output:

```
Name                                Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID                                                                
3600000e00d290000002930c300100000 253  13 L--w    0    1      0 mpath-3600000e00d290000002930c300100000
```

So how can I achieve to map on SERVER1 not the partitions. The dmsetup info on SERVER1 should look like the dmsetup info on SERVER2

The os is centos.

Comment: Do SERVER1 and SERVER2 access the disks at the same time active/active? If so, are the disks SAS/NearlineSAS disks or SATA attached? Do the partitions show up after `partprobe`?

Comment: both access the same disk over fiber channel. The disks are located on a san. And I want to avoid the partions are try no_partitions feature at multipath at the moment. Both server have the same mulitpath.conf perhaps it has to do with the multipath version

Comment: And does `partprobe` on SERVER2 read in the partition table?

Answer (score 1):

`skip_kpartx yes` is the solution.

```
defaults {
  user_friendly_names no
  skip_kpartx  yes
 find_multipaths yes  
}
```

from the man page of multipart.conf

```
skip_kpartx      If set to yes , kpartx will not automatically create partitions on the device. The default is no
```